# iOS setting view variable from view controller programmatically

Tags: ios, variables, model-view-controller, view, viewcontroller

I've created a view with a variable and loaded it in the loadView method of a view controller. How do I pass a value to the view variable from the view controller after the loadView method has been called?

**LocationView.m**

```
#import "LocationView.h"

@implementation LocationView
@synthesize locationTitle;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        locationTitle = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 20)];
        [self addSubview:locationTitle];
    }
    return self;
}
```

**LocationViewController.m**

```
#import "LocationViewController.h"
#import "LocationView.h"

@interface LocationViewController ()

@end

@implementation LocationViewController
    - (void)loadView
    {
        CGRect frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
        LocationView *locationView = [[LocationView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        [self setView:locationView];
    }

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        How do I pass a value to locationTitle here?
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already set up the `locationTitle` property for `LocationView` objects, so you can just access that.  The only thing you need to do beforehand is keep a reference to the `LocationView` object around in an instance variable so you can access it from any instance method.

```
@implementation LocationViewController {
    LocationView *_locationView;
}

- (void)loadView
{
    CGRect frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    _locationView = [[LocationView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    [self setView:_locationView];
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _locationView.locationTitle = @"Test";
}

@end
```

Alternatively, since you are assigning the custom view to the view controllers main view, you could cast that:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    ((LocationView *)self.view).locationTitle = @"Test";
}
```